# How to select the first space only, not including other characters

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I want to fix some formatted strings with 'find and replace' in Visual Studio Code.
To do so, I have to select first spaces only in each line, not including characters.

The format goes like this :

```
dc932a17 3919734822 5234dce7debe.mp4
e_f943 4961243553 03be639fa8b7.mp4
9cbcc2 4365389628 e741018829d6.mp4
543419d 4639618462 d0bd72c9b737.mp4
```

Desired outputs look like :

```
dc932a17-3919734822 5234dce7debe.mp4
e_f943-4961243553 03be639fa8b7.mp4
9cbcc2-4365389628 e741018829d6.mp4
543419d-4639618462 d0bd72c9b737.mp4
```

So what I want to select are :

```
dc932a17 3919734822 5234dce7debe.mp4
|------|^These spaces
   ^Not these characters
```

So I made an regex like this :

```
^(?:([a-zA-Z0-9_]+))\s
```

But this selects all the characters before the first space including in it.

```
dc932a17 3919734822 5234dce7debe.mp4
|-------|
    ^Selected
```

Is there anything I got wrong?

condition:
The characters' length before spaces vary. I can't use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+Drag selection

Comment: Is replacing the first whitespace character chunk after the first non-whitespace char chunk with a hyphen enough?

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the tip! I think that is also a great skill, but I wanted to know the exact how-tos while learning regex. Now I got there's no clear way to select those with a single layer of regex only(I mean like, not using any other functions except replaces, using no variables...). Thank you for teaching me how to fish!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

**Find**: `^(\S+)\s+`
**Replace**: `$1-`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qWtQFW/1).

**Note**: If there are any leading whitespace chars on the qualifyinf line, you need to add `\s*` after `^(`, i.e. `^(\s*\S+)\s+`.

[image]

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `(\s*\S+)` - Group 1 (`$1`): zero or more whitespace chars (but not line break chars here since the pattern does not contain `\r` or `\n`) and then one or more non-whitespace chars
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces (except line break chars).